# Simplifying Wordpress shortcodes

Tags: wordpress

I've made a plugin for a client to embed videos and links to videos into a post using shortcodes.

But this is still to difficult for the client, how can I go about inserting those shortcodes into a post via a wysiwyg?

Is there a way to have a form that will populate the post, i can use wp_insert_post (or insert into post, somehow) thereon but how do i add an interface to the "new post" screen so that it can get processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress-shortcodes-the-right-way/ what you are looking for?